# How do you get PHP to return the timezone abbreviation AEST?

Tags: php, timezone

I can't seem to find a way to get Pear's Date class (or PHP's date function) to return AEST as the timezone abbreviation for the timezone Australia/Melbourne. It always returns EST. I tried all the ways of printing out the timezone available in Date::format, format2, format3. Anyone know how to fix this? I'm running PHP 5.1.6, Pear Date 1.5.0a1, and the latest PECL timezonedb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you checked what it says in the time zone database for Australia/Melbourne?  It is probably based on the [Olson](ftp://elsie.nci.nih.gov/pub/) database, and when I last looked (2009a edition), it was still saying EST is the abbreviation for Australia/Melbourne.  So, unless you have fixed the time zone database to say AEST, it is likely to continue to say EST.  This has been debated on the TZ mailing list a few times; there isn't a settled answer, so the abbreviation remains unchanged.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I read through the comments in the Olson tzdata2009b file and see what you mean about the debate. It looks like I do have EST in my timezone db, so I'll just stick with that.